# Инициализация нескольких переменных

Tags: c++, инициализация

Можно ли в *C++* объявить несколько переменных и сразу присвоить одинаковое значение? Пример:

```
int a, b, c, d = 0;
```

Чтобы все переменные равны были `0`.

Answer (score 13):

Объявить несколько переменных и затем присвоить им одно и тоже значение не составляет проблему. Вы можете написать, например

```
int a, b, c, d;

a = b = c = d = 0;
```

Однако если вы хотите инициализировать переменные при их объявлении, то придется каждую переменную инициализировать отдельно. Например

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
```

или

```
int a = 0, b = a, c = a, d = a;
```

Простое объявление в C++ определяется следующим образом (7 Declarations)

> The simple-declaration

```
attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt init-declarator-listopt;
```

где  init-declarator-list определяется как (8 Declarators)

> init-declarator-list:

```
init-declarator
init-declarator-list , init-declarator
```

> init-declarator:

```
declarator initializeropt
```

То есть каждый декларатор (для простоты: объявляемый идентификатор) в списке имеет свой собственный инициализатор.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать [инициализацию из составного объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/617388/176217), появившуюся в c++17:

```
#include <array>
auto [a, b, c, d] = std::array<int, 4>();
```

Или в более общем случае для инициализации разными значениями:

```
auto [a, b, c, d] = std::array<int, 4>{{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }};
```

Такой вариант с большой долей вероятности компилятором будет развернут в тот же код, что и при использовании явной ручной инициализации вида:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
```

Однако мне кажется проще и правильнее сразу использовать массив, а не индивидуальные разноимённые переменные.

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно как-то так поступить:

```
struct vars
{
     int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p;
     vars()
     {
           ZeroMemory(this,sizeof(vars));
     }
};
```

Comment: Что такое `ZeroMemory`?

Comment: @ANT функция из WinAPI. Обнуляет байты по заданному адресу.

Comment: @gbg: Думаю, можно было бы не использовать `ZeroMemory`, а просто объявить экземпляр структуры как `vars v = {};`.