# Новый синтаксис объявления переменных, получаемых из составного объекта

Tags: c++, c++17

В c++17 появился новый синтаксис объявления переменных вида:

```
auto [x, y, z] = f();
```

где `f()` - функция, возвращающая составной объект (массив, кортеж, структуру и т.п.).

Как называется этот синтаксис и что он делает?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Данная конструкция называется [*Structured binding declaration*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind) (Можно перевести как "объявление структурированной привязки") и позволяет объявлять сразу группу переменных (возможно даже разного типа) при наличии инициализирующего выражения. В качестве этого выражения в примере используется функция `f`.

Рассмотрим несколько примеров использования:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>

struct S {
    int i;
    std::string s;
    double d;
};

S f() { return { 42, "hello", 1.5 }; }

std::map<int, std::string> g() { return { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 3, "three" } }; }

int main() {

    auto [i, s, d] = f();
    std::cout << i << s << d << "\n";

    int a[] = { 5, 6, 7 };
    auto& [x, y, z] = a;
    std::cout << x << y << z << "\n";
    x--; y++; z*=2;
    std::cout << a[0] << a[1] << a[2] << "\n";

    auto [ss, dd, ii] = std::make_tuple("ololo", 0.5, 100500);
    std::cout << ss << dd << ii << "\n";

    for (auto [k, v] : g()) {
        std::cout << "key=" << k << " value=" << v << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Результат выполнения:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/37NbAVuuZhi465MW)

> ```
> 42hello1.5
> 567
> 4714
> ololo0.5100500
> key=1 value=one
> key=2 value=two
> key=3 value=three
> ```

Можно видеть, что переменные `i`, `s`, `d` проинициализировались значениями соответствующих членов структуры `S`. Здесь стоит заметить, что важно не совпадение имён, а порядок членов.

При связывании переменных `x`, `y`, `z` с элементами массива `a` была использована ссылка `&`. Т.о. последующее изменение переменных затрагивает состояние элементов массива.

Переменные `ss`, `dd`, `ii` инициализированы элементами кортежа. Тут вроде бы всё просто.

Использование в цикле по диапазону позволяет сразу разбивать составной элемент (в данном случае `std::pair`) на компоненты. Аналогичный цикл в стиле c++11 мог бы выглядеть так:

```
for (auto e: g())
{
    std::cout << "key=" << e.first << " value=" << e.second << "\n";
}
```

Т.о. данная конструкция упрощает написание кода при необходимости доступа к частям составного объекта.

Comment: Я не вполне понял, что будет, если количество выражений слева и справа не совпадёт. UB?

Comment: @VladD число элементов с обоих сторон известно на момент компиляции, поэтому просто будет ошибка компиляции. До UB не дойдет.

Comment: Хм. А если `f` возвращает массив (причём не по ссылке)?

Comment: @VladD функция должна возвращать такой тип, который позволяет определить кол-во членов на этапе компиляции. Если будет обычный указатель, то просто не соберётся.