# Structured bindings

Tags: c++, терминология, c++17

Стандарт C++17 [вводит](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf) новый элемент синтаксиса под названием [structured bindings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). В скором времени применение этой фичи может стать широко распространённым в качестве более читаемой замены для [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) и как основной способ получения [нескольких](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2B%2B/487/returning-several-values-from-a-function#t=201708030843250044968) возвращаемых значений из функции.

У меня простой вопрос (надеюсь, не оффтоп): а как это по русски? Есть ли устоявшийся русскоязычный термин для structured bindings и structured binding declarations в русском языке? Возможно, адекватный термин уже есть в какой-нибудь теоретической области в математике?

Если нет, то каковы ваши предложения?

Comment: Выглядит как tuple, это случайно не _кортежи_?

Comment: @VladD нет, это определённо не кортежи. И семантика у *этого* не кортежная. Такие объявления всего лишь "растаскивают" агрегаты на куски. То есть одним объявлением мы объявляем несколько переменных, а вся их совокупность при этом не получает отдельного имени. Более того, кортежи - это устоявшееся название для `std::tuple`.

Comment: Декортежирование :)

Comment: @int3 декортежування :) На самом деле, это не единственный способ использования. Я тут [задал вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480824/what-are-use-cases-for-structured-bindings) об использовании на глобальном SO, и уже прилетело пара развёрнутых ответов.

Comment: «Легкоусва-ивае-мого» (ц)

Comment: Помню, [писал об этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/617389/176217). Название только вот изменилось.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, ещё нет какого-то устоявшегося перевода термина "structured bindings" на русский. Особенно учитывая, что и англоязычное название [колбасило в разные строны](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43907939/3240681) в процессе утверждения стандарта.

Более того, даже такой популярный термин как "statement" [переводится в разной литературе по-разному](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/7583/8502). Нужно чтобы прошло время, вышло несколько книг по c++17, а потом и переводы к ним, после чего в сообществе разработчиков, наверное, сможет устояться какое-то единое (или хотя бы наиболее популярное) мнение.

Может быть, недавно созданная [РГ21 (c++)](https://stdcpp.ru/) сможет посодействовать утверждению подходящего перевода. Но не думаю, что они смогут утвердить какое-то название лучше, чем это сделают время и переводы различных статей и книг. Да и вряд ли утверждение переводов входит в их круг задач.

Моё предложение перевода "structured bindings" как ["структурированные привязки"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/617389/176217). Разрешаю пользоваться всем, кому нравится, с указанием авторства, конечно :) Тем не менее, во избежании недопонимания и различных толкований всегда можно употреблять оригинальный термин.