# Как вернуть через функцию два значения в C++?

Tags: c++, функции, структурное-связывание

Суть :
Допустим у нас есть функция, в результате выполнения действий внутри нее мы получаем значения переменных, которые нам необходимо вернуть. Как это сделать? И как при вызове присвоить эти значения двум переменным одновременно?

Comment: Передать указатель на одно из возвращаемых значений и записать по нему. Второе - через return, например.

Comment: Как этим указателем воспользоваться вне функции, можно пример?

Comment: Читайте учебники про указатели и ссылки

Comment: Используйте [structured binding](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/617388/176217).

Answer (score 8):

Варианты:

1. вернуть структуру или кортеж (пару) с двумя полями
2. использовать передачу параметров по ссылке или через указатель.

Например, считать сумму и разность двух переменных:

```
std::pair<int,int> sumdif(ina a, int b)
{
    return pair<int,int>(a+b,a-b);
}

void sumdif(int a, int b, int& sum, int& dif)
{
    sum = a+b;
    dif = a-b;
}

...

int a = 5, b = 7;

auto p = sumdif(a,b);
cout << "Sum = " << p.first << ", Dif = " << p.second << endl;
```

или

```
int a = 5, b = 7, s, d;
sumdif(a,b,s,d);
cout << "Sum = " << s << ", Dif = " << d << endl;
```

Дополнение через 3 года :) - теперь можно использовать новый вариант синтаксиса структурного связывания:

```
std::pair<int,int> sumdif(int a, int b)
{
    return pair<int,int>(a+b,a-b);
}

....

int a = 5, b = 7;
auto [s,d] = sumdif(a,b);
cout << "Sum = " << s << ", Dif = " << d << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ @Harry

Если под рукой компилятор с поддержкой 11 ого (и выше)  стандарта, то можно воспользоваться `std::tuple` и вернуть его из функции, эдакое обобщение на `std::pair` для произвольноно числа элементов с разными типами

```
std::tuple<int, int> f()
{
    std::tuple<int, int> t = { -1, 123 };
    //  ...
    return t;
}

std::tuple<int, const bool, unsigned> g()
{
    std::tuple<int, const bool, unsigned> t = { -1, false, 123 };
    //  ...
    return t;
}
```